# Download single file from remote branch

Tags: github

Is there a way to download a single file from a specific branch of Git Remote repository?

```
Repo_URL:https://test.ghe.com/repo.git
Branch:release
Git relative file path: repo/file01.txt
```

There are many related threads however in none gives idea about how to use a specific Git remote branch.

Please help.

Thanks.
Kumarjit

Comment: I don't know how to download just a single file, unless GitHub exposes some API for this.  However, you of course do a clone as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the raw URL for your file, follow below steps.

1) Open your repo and required branch in github website.

2) Navigate to the folder containing your desired file.

3) On top of the file, you see "Raw" button.

4) Click on that and you see the raw URL in address bar.

5) You can use this URL to download the file, for example using curl.

However, I'm not sure about your use case, but it is always better to use git pull to get the file.

Hope this helps!